# Upload Excel and Split Into Multiple Files Based On Date Value with PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm stuck in my coding...

I created file upload and get the value from the uploaded file (excel)
then I wanna split into multiples file based on uploaded file..
How to do that?

I just created file that successfully created multiples file but the value in its file creating that I don't want to...

This is example file I upload (.xlxs)

```
store_number | order_number | business_date | item_number | description

123          | 123.1        | 2019-02-01    | AA1         | tea

123          | 123.2        | 2019-02-01    | AA1         | tea 

124          | 124.1        | 2019-02-01    | AA3         | coffee

124          | 124.1        | 2019-02-02    | AA2         | juice
```

So, based on the excel file, when I uploaded this..
I wanna split into 3 file based on store_number and business_date

```
123_2019-02-01

124_2019-02-01

124_2019-02-02
```

How to do that? Thanks

Comment: Do you have some code of what you have tried?

Comment: I suggest you go with extracting all the data from the excel first, then literate through the data, then put them into groups by `store_number` and `business_date`, then export those groups into separate files. That would be the logic I would go about doing this.

Comment: TriDiamond I did that with extract and input into temporary table, then select them. but the item number inside split file doubled and show in every split

Comment: @JoeWilson, you don't really need to store them into tables, you can just process the data using array data, anyway, dump out the data you select from your table, is it doubled already? or is doubled after your have exported into the excel file.

Comment: You can put your data into an array with key names like this to make sure no doubles, use `store_number` and `business_date`, join them together like 123_2019-02-01 as array's key names. This will make sure each data is unique. Shouldn't have doubles.